# Adding data.frame to email with mailR

Tags: r

Im trying to send an email from r using the mailR package. The email is very simple, all I need is for it to display a data.frame in the body of the email.

I am able to send an email using the code below but am struggling to add the data.frame to the body of it.

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "email@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("email@gmail.com")

email <- send.mail(from = sender,
to = recipients,
subject="Subject",
body = "Body",
smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
authenticate = FALSE,
send = FALSE)

email$send()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is the data frame in the code that you have used so far?

Comment: It should be as simple as `body <- paste0(capture.output(mtcars), collapse = "\n")`, but I suspect you'll run into problems with rendering a data frame.  The common e-mail clients don't render in a monospace font, so your columns won't align correctly.

Comment: Generate a picture of the message and send that. Not searchable, though. :)

Comment: @Benjamin I tried the code you suggested and it worked, but like you mentioned the columns don't align. Do you know how to make them align??

Comment: The problem with the alignment isn't an R problem. It's that R is using a monospace font where a space is the same width as a character; the email client is using a font where the space is only between 50-70% of a character (and in some fonts, the width of a character varies). The only reliable solution is to switch the email client to a monospace font; not a very reliable solution at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: Your only reliable options for a tabular display are to send the table as an attachment (in an HTML or plain text file), or generate an image of the table to place in the body of the e-mail. With an attachment, there's an extra step to see the data. With an image, you lose searchable text.

Answer (score 11):

Below is a solution that works for me. You need to convert the data frame into an HTML table using `htmlTable` package. See details below.

```
library(mailR)
library(htmlTable)

# Create a reproducible data frame
x <- head(mtcars)

# Convert the data frame into an HTML Table
y <- htmlTable(x, rnames = FALSE)

# Define body of email
html_body <- paste0("<p> This is a test email. </p>", y)

# Configure details to send email using mailR
sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("RECEIPENT@gmail.com")

send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Test Email",
          body = html_body,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",
                      port = 465, 
                      user.name = "USERID@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "PASSWORD",
                      ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          html = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Below is how to output looks like in gmail.

[image]

If you want a table with borders, use the below code. This uses a little bit of CSS to format the table.

```
library(mailR)
library(htmlTable)

x <- head(mtcars)
y <- htmlTable(x, rnames = FALSE)

html_body <- paste0("<html><head>
               <style>
               body{font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;}
               table{border-left:1px solid #000000;border-top:1px solid #000000;}
               table th{border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; margin: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0px;}
               table td{border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;font-size:13px; font-weight:normal; margin: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0px;}
               </style>
               </head><body><p> This is a test email. Ignore it.</p>",
               y, 
               "</body></html>")

sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("RECIPIENTS@gmail.com")

send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Test Email",
          body = html_body,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",
                      port = 465, 
                      user.name = "USERNAME@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "PASSWORD",
                      ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          html = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Below is a screenshot of how the table looks like in gmail.

[image]